# Trouble with SQL Query Using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Answer**

***$this->db->set('page_routes','pageid', $newid);***

Should have been

**$this->db->update('page_routes', array('pageid' => $newid));**

I am trying to create a page where, you can submit a form and it update values based on what you select, I cannot see what I am doing wrong but at some point, I think I am erring with regards to the MySQL command.

The idea is you select a page(friendly name) on the top option-select, and on the bottom you set the ID to the value of another pageID.

The effect it should be achieving is that the user can change change what content is displayed on a particular page.

**Question: According to the query return, the update runs, but nothing is changed in my page_routes table**

**My View, the values are pulled from the database, they populate correctly.**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('/view/updatepageid'); ?>" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="friendly_name">Page</label>
  <div class="controls">
            <select id="friendlyname" name="friendlyname" class="input-xlarge">
        <?php foreach($pageroutes as $key): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key['friendly_name']; ?>"><?php echo $key['friendly_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Change to:</label>
  <div class="controls">
        <select  onchange="this.form.submit();" id="newid" name="newid">
        <?php foreach($page_data as $key): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>"><?php echo $key['pagetitle']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

**Which submits to here**

```
function updatepageid(){
    $this->load->model('view_model');
    $friendlyname = $this->input->post('friendlyname');
    $newid = $this->input->post('newid');


    $query = $this->view_model->setpageid($friendlyname, $newid);

    if($query == TRUE){
        echo 'updated';
    }else { echo 'failed'; }

    var_dump($query);


}
```

**and my Model view_model setpageid function**

```
function setpageid($friendlyname, $newid){
    $this->db->where('friendly_name', $friendlyname);
    $query = $this->db->set('page_routes','pageid', $newid);
    return $query;
}
```

If I var_dump($query) it returns

```
Object(CI_DB_mysql_driver)[14]
  public 'dbdriver' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
  public '_escape_char' => string '`' (length=1)
  public '_like_escape_str' => string '' (length=0)
  public '_like_escape_chr' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'delete_hack' => boolean true
  public '_count_string' => string 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ' (length=19)
  public '_random_keyword' => string ' RAND()' (length=7)
  public 'use_set_names' => boolean false
  public 'ar_select' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_distinct' => boolean false
  public 'ar_from' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_join' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_where' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '`friendly_name` =  'aboutus'' (length=28)
  public 'ar_like' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_groupby' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_having' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_keys' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_limit' => boolean false
  public 'ar_offset' => boolean false
  public 'ar_order' => boolean false
  public 'ar_orderby' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_set' => 
    array (size=1)
      '`page_routes`' => string ''pageid'' (length=8)
  public 'ar_wherein' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_aliased_tables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_store_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_caching' => boolean false
  public 'ar_cache_exists' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_select' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_from' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_join' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_where' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_like' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_groupby' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_having' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_orderby' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_set' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_no_escape' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ar_cache_no_escape' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'username' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'hostname' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  public 'database' => string 'cms' (length=3)
  public 'dbprefix' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'char_set' => string 'utf8' (length=4)
  public 'dbcollat' => string 'utf8_general_ci' (length=15)
  public 'autoinit' => boolean true
  public 'swap_pre' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'port' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'pconnect' => boolean true
  public 'conn_id' => resource(50, mysql link persistent)
  public 'result_id' => resource(57, mysql result)
  public 'db_debug' => boolean true
  public 'benchmark' => float 0.00099992752075195
  public 'query_count' => int 1
  public 'bind_marker' => string '?' (length=1)
  public 'save_queries' => boolean true
  public 'queries' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'SELECT *
FROM (`sessions`)
WHERE `session_id` =  '93072e3813e9ac20216c8cf6affc1d1b'
AND `user_agent` =  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0'' (length=171)
  public 'query_times' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => float 0.00099992752075195
  public 'data_cache' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'trans_enabled' => boolean true
  public 'trans_strict' => boolean true
  public '_trans_depth' => int 0
  public '_trans_status' => boolean true
  public 'cache_on' => boolean false
  public 'cachedir' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'cache_autodel' => boolean false
  public 'CACHE' => null
  public '_protect_identifiers' => boolean true
  public '_reserved_identifiers' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  public 'stmt_id' => null
  public 'curs_id' => null
  public 'limit_used' => null
  public 'stricton' => boolean false
```

If I have missed anything relevant to helping trouble shoot, please let me know, **Thank you for your time**, I believe it something simple I am missing, as I am self taught and my understanding isn't thorough as I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
function setpageid($friendlyname, $newid)
{
    $this->db->where('friendly_name', $friendlyname);
    $this->db->update('page_routes', array('pageid' => $newid));

    return $this->db->affected_rows()>0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

This will update the `page_routes` table, specifically the `pageid` column, with the value of `$newid` where `friendly_name = $friendlyname`.

It will then return either boolean true or false, whether any rows were affected.

I hope this is what you mean?

Comment: Hi, thank you Phil, yes it was the $this->db->update('page_routes', array('pageid' => $newid)); syntax I had wrong, using yours it works as intended, the var_dump'ing of $query was to try work out what I was doing wrong and is irrelevant to what I am trying to achieve, sorry for the confusion! Will accept when it lets me :).